# sqlalchemy: rename a column on *query* level

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to rename a column in a query, but I can't do it on column level, eg

```
session.query(MyModel.col_name.label('new_name'))
```

Is there any way to rename a column on the resulting *query* object?

Eg, something like

```
session.query(...).blah().blah().rename_column('old_name', 'new_name')
```

Comment: `MyModel.col_name.label('new_name')`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä: sorry, I had a typo. That's what I wanted to avoid, I need to rename column *after* the `query()` call.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's any built in solution for that – but here's a workaround I've implemented which may help you:

**To rename before the query has been executed:**

```
# Start off with your regular query – but as a subquery
query = session.query(MyModel.col_name.label('old_name')).subquery()

# Now, perform a second query with new labels
query_2 = session.query(query.c.old_name.label('new_name'))

# Or, if there's only one column:
query_3 = session.query(query.label('new_name'))
```

Comment: Hmm, I want to keep the return value the entities, but rename the column names. I'm running into an issue where using `except_` prefixes the table name onto the column names so I can no longer reference things in a subsequent subquery by its original name. This makes for some awkward code that has to try both names in some cases. Do you know how you can attach these columns to a particular entity?

Comment: Interesting problem. Why don't you ask as a new Q and share the link with me and I'll do my best to answer? @BT

Comment: Previously I asked this question here, but I've just found an answer actually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588253/how-do-you-prevent-sqlalchemy-from-prefixing-column-names-when-using-except/74480409#74480409 .

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do this. In my case, I was having issues with `except_`, which prefixes columns with the table name. Here's how I did that:

```
def _except(included_query, excluded_query, Model, prefix):
    """An SQLALchemy except_ that removes the prefixes on the columns, so they can be
    referenced in a subquery by their un-prefixed names."""
    query = included_query.except_(excluded_query)
    subquery = query.subquery()
    # Get a list of columns from the subquery, relabeled with the simple column name.
    columns = []
    for column_name in _attribute_names(Model):
        column = getattr(subquery.c, prefix + column_name)
        columns.append(column.label(column_name))
    # Wrap the query to select the simple column names. This is necessary because
    # except_ prefixes column names with a string derived from the table name.
    return Model.query.from_statement(Model.query.with_entities(*columns).statement)
```