# How do you prevent SQLAlchemy from prefixing column names when using except_

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query like the following:

```
query = included_query.except_(excluded_query)
```

Both `included_query` and `excluded_query` query over a particular model called TestModel. However, when I create a subquery with that query (ie `subquery = query.subquery()`), instead of having the direct columns of TestModel (eg `subquery.c.id`) it instead prefixes all the columns (eg `subquery.c.test_models_id`).

I have tried using `with_entitites` to return the columns in the right name, however if I do that, it no longer returns a list of TestModel objects and instead returns a tuple of column values.

How can I return TestModel objects while retaining the correct column names (without prefixing)?

I see there's a related question about this here with no answer:

- [SQLAlchemy : column name prefixed on the subquery of union_all of 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405187/sqlalchemy-column-name-prefixed-on-the-subquery-of-union-all-of-3-tables)

Comment: I don't understand the problem?  If I create a subquery as described in the question, and use it in a WHERE clause on a query on `TestModel`, I get `TestModel` instances in the result.  Can you provide a runnable example?

Comment: Yes, I also get `TestModel` instance as a result, that isn't the problem. The problem is the column names you get when you `.subquery()` the query. I'm getting `subquery.c.test_models_id` instead of `subquery.c.id`

Comment: I don't get that behaviour.  Again, please provide a runnable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way to do this:

```
def _except(included_query, excluded_query, Model, prefix):
    """An SQLALchemy except_ that removes the prefixes on the columns, so they can be
    referenced in a subquery by their un-prefixed names."""
    query = included_query.except_(excluded_query)
    subquery = query.subquery()
    # Get a list of columns from the subquery, relabeled with the simple column name.
    columns = []
    for column_name in _attribute_names(Model):
        column = getattr(subquery.c, prefix + column_name)
        columns.append(column.label(column_name))
    # Wrap the query to select the simple column names. This is necessary because
    # except_ prefixes column names with a string derived from the table name.
    return Model.query.from_statement(Model.query.with_entities(*columns).statement)
```